# How I can make costume FlixelCrashHandler.exe

Tags: haxeflixel

In Fnf Indie cross mod I found FlixelCrashHandler.exe Can you tell me how to do that in my mod

Answer (score 1):

Indie Cross developer here.

The file you're referring to (FlixelCrashHandler.exe) is an executable we made ourselves for the mod, and it's source code is not available online.

However, it's just a simple crash handler for HaxeFlixel, which can be done using OpenFL's `UncaughtErrorEvent` and [`haxeui-wxwidgets`](http://haxeui.org/getting-started/haxeui-hxwidgets/).

Check out the HaxeUI and OpenFL API and you will have your own crash handler!